# How do I take strings from a list using an integer?

Tags: python, list, variables, integer

How do I take strings from a list using an integer?

I tried this but it just gives an error:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
listlength = (len(list) + 1)
int1 = 1
int2 = 1
while (int1 < listlength):
    int2 = list[int1]
    print(int2)
    int3 = (int1 + 1)
    int1 = (int3)
```

On the line where I'm trying to set `int2` to be the part of the `list` that is 1, since `int1` is 1, if `int1` was 2, I would want 2. The code is how I set it up on my computer and it doesn't work. It just says this:

```
    int2 = list[int1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: your `int2` ect are still strings of length 1 - what do you want to accomplish? creating `[1,2,3,4]` from `['1','2','3','4']` ? lists are 0 based, your listlength makes not much sense - the len() of your list is 4, its indexes range from 0,1,2,3 thats why you get an IndexError

Comment: @PatrickArtner: where do you see `int1` being set to a string?

Comment: Why did you add 1 to `listLength`? Python indices start at *zero*, not 1.

Comment: @MartijnPieters typo,thx

Comment: You might also avoid using names that python already uses as variable-names - this includes the builtins: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html  - and most datatypes like `list, set, frozenset, dict, tuple`...

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am, just I used those as variable names for this question, im not actually using them in my code

Comment: why are you purposefully making coding mistakes when posting your code in your question?

Comment: because its an example, i'm not actually using it

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indices that start at *zero*. The indices for your list run from 0 trough to 3, not 1 through to 4. Your code assumes that the latter is true and sets `listLength` to *5*, so when `int = 4` then `int1 < listlength` is true, but `list[4]` fails because that index doesn't exist.

Start `int1` at `0` and use `listlength = len(list)` instead, to run from 0 through to 3.

Note that Python has much better tools to loop over a list. Use the [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to just loop directly over the values:

```
for int2 in list:
    print(int2)
```

That's much simpler and less likely to go wrong.

Note that it's not a good idea to use the name `list` as a variable, because that masks the built-in `list` type. You'd be better of with different names:

```
values = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for value in values:
    print(value)
```

or, if you must use `while`:

```
values = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
values_length = len(values)
index = 0
while index < values_length:
    value = values[index]
    print(value)
    index = index + 1
```

Comment: `print(*values,sep="\n")` would be another way to go

Comment: @PatrickArtner: the OP almost certainly will need to do more with the values once they have the looping working.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: otherwise, see [Python: for loop inside print()](//stackoverflow.com/a/20774626) for information on how that works.